# Can multiple Form 4868 be placed in same envelope?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, mailing

When filing automatic extension of time to file with no tax due, can multiple extensions with the same address be placed in the same envelope or need they be mailed individually?

Comment: I've always assumed 1 envelope per filing, but I'm not sure if that's law or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some research and it appears they can be mailed together.  Here are the instructions for how the IRS processes when multiple forms are in the same envelope.

> Occasionally multiple forms
>   1040/A/EZ/X are attached. For example:
>
> Two or more returns from the same
>   taxpayer are mailed in the same
>   envelope
>
> Two or more family members' returns
>   are mailed by the tax preparer in the
>   same envelope
>
> Two or more unrelated returns are
>   mailed by the tax preparer in the same
>   envelope
>
> Note:
>
> Detach the returns leaving an action
>   trail on each document, then sort,
>   work or route the returns as
>   appropriate.

[Source](http://www.irs.gov/irm/part3/irm_03-011-006.html)

However, the IRS is tracking an issue in their issue system about multiple filings in the same envelope and several getting marked as late.

> IMRS 10-0001371 – Multiple Forms 7004
>   (Request for Extension) mailed in one
>   envelope Issue: A tax professional
>   mailed multiple Forms 7004 (Request
>   for Extension) in one envelope to
>   Ogden, postmarked 3/15/10. Six of
>   these were rejected, with the taxpayer
>   receiving Form 6513 stating the
>   extension was not approved because it
>   was filed after the date the return
>   was due.

[Source](http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/article/0,,id=236873,00.html)

So because the IRS has had a recent problem with multiple filings in the same envelope, I would go ahead and use more than one envelope.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask yourself the following: Is it worth the extra (calculate postage & envelope cost) to deal with the time and hassle on the phone and in paperwork for the IRS if it doesn't get filed properly? To me, the answer is NO WAY. I'd rather pay the extra 60 cents per return.

BTW: One stamp = 4-5 standard pages in a standard envelope; Two stamps for 5-10 pages.